# UNbound Text Box wont save

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form onto which I have placed an unbound text box. This box is designed to calculate the total of 4 other bound text boxes which have simple numerical values in. I have used the expression builder in the unbound text box to set its control source property i.e. =([box1]+[box2]+[box3]+[box4])

When I first put this in it works fine. However after I close and then reopen the data base the box sits on the form saying #NAME? as if it has lost its control source. I have checked the data source after and nothing seems to be wrong. Any ideas why its happening. Its a pain as I have a button which when pressed opens a report based on the value in the unbound text box.

Comment: check the names of your 3 source controls. They might be different from the name of the underlying fields. Name the controls like the bound fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Nz*:

```
=Nz([box1],0)+Nz([box2],0)+Nz([box3],0)+Nz([box4],0)
```

Comment: Then, I guess, the form has no records.

Comment: Neither. #Name? means Acces can't solve the...names. Data has nothing to do here I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure why it now works but I have re added the text box and the calculations into the source code and it seems to be fine. Perhaps just a glitch in my previous attempt... I used the =sum solution rather than the =Nz solution. Maybe my version of access or my data base is just fickle... thanks anyway